# How do I properly concatenate this PHP echo statement with a string and a function?

Tags: php, string, function, concatenation

```
//top of the code just consists of an if statement and some code.
case 'itemimage' :

        echo '<div class="product-preview-image" style="background: red; height:75px; width:75px;"><img href=' . <?php grab_item_image(); ?> . "</div>"';
break;
    }
}
```

That was my attempt but it does not look rite on my text editor. I am also using inline-css not sure if that matters.

The only thing that i'm trying to echo out is this div with the function providing an href.

```
<div class="product-preview-image" style="background: red; height:75px; width:75px;"><img href="#thephpfunctionhere"</div>
```

It's kind of confusing me with all the single and double quotes.

Comment: `. "</div>"'` ⇒ `. '"</div>"'` :: You missed a single quote right after dot.

Comment: still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Ah, you have the image tag not closed as well. Please see an answer. Plus `img` tag supposed to have an `src` attr, not `href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes Problem and you started `<?php` again. Use the code below

```
//top of the code just consists of an if statement and some code.
case 'itemimage' :

        echo '<div class="product-preview-image" style="background: red; height:75px; width:75px;"><img src="' .  grab_item_image() . '" /></div>"';
break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Yeah thanks! just needed to remove the last double quotes because it was getting echo'd

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div class="product-preview-image" style="background: red; height:75px; width:75px;"><img src="' . <?php grab_item_image(); ?> . '"></div>"';
```

Answer (score 0):

The image needs the ''SRC'' attribute instead of href. Also, since you are echo-ing within a php-tag you don't have to open the <\?php again but directly refer to the function.

```
echo 
    '<div class="product-preview-image" style="background: red; height:75px; width:75px;">' ,
        '<img src="' .  grab_item_image() . '" />' ,
    '</div>"';
```

Komma's are even faster when using a direct echo. Not suitable for assigning it to a $variable